# Streaming files with ABP Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, streaming, abp

I'm trying to send a zip file with ABP Framework, the zip file could be large (more than 1GB) so I want to stream the file, the problem is that the zip file is generated on the fly, i do not want to use the `MemoryStream` to pass it to the `IRemoteStreamContent`, the only way i found was to create a temporal file and then send it with `IRemoteStreamContent` like:

```
var zipFile = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open);
return new RemoteStreamContent(zipFile, "File.zip", "application/zip");
```

But i would like to do something like:

```
var responseBodyStream = Response.BodyWriter.AsStream();

using ZipArchive archive = new(responseBodyStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
foreach (var file in files)
{
  var entry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
  using var entryStream = entry.Open();
  try
  {
    var blob = await BlobService.GetAsync(file.Id);
    await blob.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
    entryStream.Close();
    await responseBodyStream.FlushAsync();
  }
  catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

But I could not make it to work, is there a way to make something like this?